# Adding a double to the end of a string (C++)

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading, double

So, essentially this is essentially where my problems is occurring within my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

void main()
{
    double k = 10.0;
    string out;
    out = "V";
    out += ".";
    out << k;   <---
}
```

I attempt to compile, but I get this error:

error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,_Ty)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &&' from 'std::string'

...that is pointing at the line w/ an arrow. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `std::to_string` might help you. Also, http://stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::stringstream` or `boost::lexical_cast`.

```
out += boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(k);
```

or `std::to_string` if you can use C++11

Comment: hmm this seems to be the one most useful for me in my situation... thank you! Although I am a but unfamiliar with the boost library.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:-

```
std::ostringstream strs;
strs << dbl;
std::string str = strs.str();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a `string` instead of `stringstream`. There is no operator `<<` defined that would take `string` as its first argument, which is what the compiler is trying to tell you (in a rather cryptic way).

```
stringstream out;
out << "V." << k;
string s = out.str();
```

If you're on C++11, you can write this:

```
double k = 10.0;
string out;
out = "V";
out += ".";
out += to_string(k);
```

Comment: so what operator should I use instead of << (I would prefer nor using stringstream)

Comment: @ked why not use `stringstream`? It's just a wrapper around a `string` object.

Comment: @ked If you're on C++11, you can use `out += to_string(k)`. Before C++11, `stringstream` is your best option.

Comment: Ok, I guess I have no option but to use it... but now I am getting a compiler error saying it is an undefined class.

Comment: @ked Why can't you write your double directly to `fstream` then?

Comment: whoops, edited last comment :P but yah... why am I getting that compiler error (btw, thank you so much for help me!)

Comment: @ked You need to `#include <sstream>` to use `stringstream`; it's not in the `<iostream>` header.